# Django Form with pre loaded model data

Tags: python, django, forms, orm, model

I Have one big form to handle with django. My model is as below

```
class MerchantContact(models.Model):
    merchant = models.OneToOneField(MerchantProfile, related_name="merchant_contact")

    ContactUsAddressLine1 =models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ContactUsAddressLine2 =models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ContactUsAddressCity =models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ContactUsAddressState =models.CharField(max_length=4)
    ContactUsAddressZip=models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ContactUsPhone=models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ContactUsAddressFax=models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ContactUsEmail=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ContactUsBusinessHours=models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

I have used following logic to populate form

```
def merchantAccountInfo(request):
    #check if data is already there or not
    usr=UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    merchant=MerchantProfile.objects.get(user_id=usr.id)
    try:
        mc=MerchantContact.objects.get(merchant_id=merchant.id)
        formdata=MerchantContactForm(
                        {'id':mc.id,
                         'ContactUsAddressLine1':mc.ContactUsAddressLine1,
                        'ContactUsAddressLine2':mc.ContactUsAddressLine2,
                        'ContactUsAddressCity':mc.ContactUsAddressCity,
                        'ContactUsAddressState':mc.ContactUsAddressState,
                        'ContactUsAddressZip':mc.ContactUsAddressZip,
                        'ContactUsPhone':mc.ContactUsPhone,
                        'ContactUsAddressFax':mc.ContactUsAddressFax,
                        'ContactUsEmail':mc.ContactUsEmail,
                        'ContactUsBusinessHours':mc.ContactUsBusinessHours
                        }
        )

    except MerchantContact.DoesNotExist:
        formdata=MerchantContactForm()
    return render_to_response('account_info.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The code above is working perfectly , but my concern is that the form could be too big with 30+ fields . Passing each fields inline will be too tedious way..

Any other alternatives to save time and code lines?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `instance` parameter to instantiate form which will put initial data in the form from that object, instead of providing dict of attributes.

like:

`formdata=MerchantContactForm(instance=mc)`

Comment: That's assuming you've created a `ModelForm` and not a standard `Form`, but it should be a `ModelForm` if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to read the documentation about ModelForms. They construct a form based on the data of a model. If you want to install additional styling or widgets to the model then you can do that similar to adding in a RTE in the admin, I believe. Just go to the official docs for your version and consult the modelforms documentation. It is the quickest way to generate a form from a model. You can even set css attributes amongst other things.